# Restricting values with "enum" for a property typed with "$ref"

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have a base schema `base.json` that defines a type named `foobar`:

```
{
  "definitions": {
    "foobar": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

I then have another schema `instance.json` that builds on that type and attempts to restrict its potential values:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "raboof": {
      "$ref": "base.json#/definitions/foobar",
      "enum": [
        "this is a foobar!"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If I try to validate the following file `wrong_data.json`:

```
{
  "raboof": "not really a foobar..."
}
```

my validation tool reports no error.

I do get an error if I change `"$ref": "base.json#/definitions/foobar"` to `"type": "string"` in `instance.json` though.

Am I holding it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON Schema core specification for draft-7 (current latest) states the following in the section about `$ref`...

> An object schema with a "$ref" property MUST be interpreted as a
> "$ref" reference.  The value of the "$ref" property MUST be a URI
> Reference.  Resolved against the current URI base, it identifies the
> URI of a schema to use.  All other properties in a "$ref" object MUST
> be ignored.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-01#section-8.3

Note specifically that you can't use `$ref` with other keywords in the same object, as other keys in that object will be ignored.

You can get around this limitation by wrapping in an `allOf`...

```
{
  "allOf": [
    { "$ref": "base.json#/definitions/foobar" },
    { "enum": [ "this is a foobar!" ] }
  ]
}
```

This will be allowed in draft-8 so the work around will no longer be required, but it's not yet released.